# Weird compacting behaviour in react-grid-layout

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

I'm building a dashboard application with react-grid-layout and I experience some behaviour that I don't understand.

I have created the following codesandbox to showcase the problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-dream-b4c06?file=/src/App.js

Specifically when

- Clicking 'Add Small Box' twice I get two box, which I expected.
- However, when clicking 'Add Large Box' afterwards, the large box get positioned in the middle, vertically, with one small box above it and another small box below it.

How can this be?

NB: It is a requirement that I keep the layout in state, because I keep it in a redux store in my real application.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use onLayoutChange instead of onDragStop and onResizeStop.